# Puppet class not found because of metadata.json

Tags: puppet

I just want to add my experience here.

So I had this module, let's call it `test` for now with this directory structure :

```
/etc/puppet
   |- modules
         |- test
         |    |- manifests
         |          |- init.pp
         |    |- metadata.json
         |    |- README.md
         |    |- Modulefile
         |    |- LICENSE
```

Content of `init.pp` is simply `class test(){}`

Trying to do a `include test` always resulted in `Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Could not find declared class`.

It turns out that my `metadata.json` was the problem. Indeed, here is what the content I had

```
    {
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "TEST",
  "license": "Apache License, Version 2.0",
  "summary": "TEST",
  "source": "",
  "project_page": "https://github.com/test/test"
     }
```

Adding the `dependencies` key solved my issue.

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "TEST",
  "license": "Apache License, Version 2.0",
  "summary": "TEST",
  "source": "",
  "project_page": "https://github.com/test/test"
  "dependencies": [

  ]
}
```

Notice how the project page is missing a `,` at the end ? Well, this made it work anyways even if the metadata.json is not valid json.

My question is : what the hell is going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is known bug reported here :

https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-5723?jql=project%20%3D%20PUP%20AND%20text%20~%20metadata.json